# Keep getting this error i have no idea

Tags: android

```
    TextView drawerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawerName);
    TextView drawerEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawerEmail);
    CircleImageView drawerAvatar = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.drawerAvatar);

    drawerName.setText(personName);
    drawerEmail.setText(personEmail);
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: com.mje.dev.liqourstore, PID: 1537
>                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mje.dev.liqourstore/com.mje.dev.liqourstore.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                                                        at com.mje.dev.liqourstore.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:146)
>                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
>                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681) 
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: from you error log,we can see your drawerName or drawerEmail is null,please check these first.

Comment: I think he's just a new person come to Android. Post a link like "What is null pointer exception" doesn't help him. Close this post doesn't help him either. And nonsense,too. He correctly post a code that he sees error.

Comment: Please post your layout file for this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    TextView drawerName = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.navDrawerName);
    TextView drawerEmail = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.navDrawerEmail);
    CircleImageView  drawerAvatar = (CircleImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.avatar);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you haven't set the `View` of `Activity` by setting contentView as `setContentView`. Furthermore, please also check that `setContentView` layout also have the `textview` you are fetching.

hope this helps.

Comment: I just found out that i had ids that were conflicting with the new design library. Thanks though.